# Accessing multiple TextBoxes InputScope property in a single event in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP project where I have multiple textboxes in the `UI` i have attached `x:Name` property with them . I have binded all `Textboxes` with a single `KeyButton_Down()` event. I want to implement setting the `InputScope` property of every `TextBox` as `Number`. the XAML of every textbox has the `InputScope="Number"` set. In the code behind, I am unable to access the InputScope property of the specific `Textbox`.
Here is my code

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

            InputScope scope = new InputScope();
            InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();
            name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number;
            scope.Names.Add(name);
            string textBoxName = tb.Name;
          //  TextBox text = new TextBox();

            //this line is not working for me
           // textBoxName.InputScope = scope;
            var state = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);
            var newState = (state & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;


            if ((!char.IsControl(Convert.ToChar(e.Key)) && !char.IsDigit(Convert.ToChar(e.Key)) && (Convert.ToChar(e.Key) != '.') && !newState))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Does it throw an exception?

Comment: @Laith I want to use the Textbox name from the (sender) ;tb.Name.Visibility is not there

Comment: @Apoorv: if you like to access some property you will not need the name. The tb is your `TextBox` casted specific object. You can use the properties directly as: `tb.Visibility`. Like I posted in my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the sender directly (it points to the specific `TextBox` you like to have access to).

```
tb.InputScope = new InputScope();
tb.InputScope.Names.Clear();
tb.InputScope.Names.Add(new InputScopeNameConverter().ConvertFrom(InputScopeNameValue.Number.ToString()));
```

your `tb` is to `TextBox` casted sender object...

Comment: this is perfect ! I just got confused . Thanks for your help